# Why "ich rutsche auf meinem Stuhl hin und her" not accusative as there is some movement?

Tags: preposition

> ich rutsche auf mein**em** Stuhl hin und her

In the sentence above I think that there is some movement, so why doesn't it use accusative?

Comment: Does the accepted answer of the following question answer your question as well? [Accusative or dative case, how to detect "action" and "movement"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39879/accusative-or-dative-case-how-to-detect-action-and-movement)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck I'm afraid not, cause I think in the sentence I mentioned above there is also some movement with _hin und her_ but still the dative is used.

Comment: It's not movement per se, but direction that implies accusative. Here you are at a chair and stay at the chair, that is, there is no other direction involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no movement from elsewhere to the chair. The entire action you describe (moving/shifting forth and back) takes place at the same location (on the chair), hence dative is correct here.

Comment: The "movement rule" is being oversimplified here. It's not "movement" in general but "change of location". So *Fische schwimmen im Wasser* (dative) even though "swimming" is movement.